# How to reduce SPI bit errors between a Bus Pirate and a BIOS chip?

Tags: communication, spi, data, signal-integrity, serial-bus

I need to eliminate bit errors when reading a [BIOS chip](http://www.macronix.com/en-us/Product/Pages/ProductDetail.aspx?PartNo=MX25L6406E) using a [Bus Pirate v3.6](https://www.adafruit.com/products/237).

The BIOS chip is still soldered onto the motherboard.  I'm using a [Bus Pirate probe set](https://www.adafruit.com/products/238) to connect the Bus Pirate to a [SOIC test clip](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014IXR9RG).

Here's a diagram:

```
laptop  ---usb--->  bus pirate  ---probes---> ---clip--->  BIOS IC
```

The motherboard has power but is not booted (the computer's power supply is plugged in but the computer is not turned on).  I needed to plug in the computer to power the BIOS chip; powering the BIOS from the Bus Pirate didn't work (maybe because the Bus Pirate's weak power supply was trying to power the whole motherboard via the BIOS VCC pin).

Using [flashrom](http://flashrom.org/) I can read the BIOS chip, except I get lots of bit errors (about one every 400k bits).  The Bus Pirate is configured to use a 30kHz clock (the lowest setting).

Is there anything I can do to reduce the bit error rate without desoldering the SOP8 BIOS chip?

Bus Pirate SPI settings:

- Clock polarity: "Idle low" (CPOL=0, I think).  (The other option is "Idle high".)
- Output clock edge: "Active to idle".  (The other option is "Idle to active".)
- Input sample phase: "Middle".  (The other option is "End".)  I'm not sure what this means, but "Middle" is the default.
- Output type: "Normal (H=3.3V, L=GND)".  (The other option is "Open drain (H=Hi-Z, L=GND)".)

Unfortunately flashrom has the above settings hard-coded, so if they're not right for my BIOS chip then I'll have to edit the source code and recompile.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right SPI mode?

Comment: @crasic:  Updated my question.

Comment: SPI mode is correct. The bios chips supports Mode 0 and Mode 3. You settings are Mode 0 (CPOL=0, CPHA=0). Note that "Active to Idle" means the edge where the clock goes from its active value to its idle value (the idle value being the clock polarity setting).